proper vertical flashing to transition from brick to aluminum siding
I have a part of my house where aluminum siding hits a brick mason wall. What is the proper way to install vertical flashing against the brick where they meet? Should I chisel out a half inch line in the brick to provide a flat surface to install vertical flashing to? Right now the existing flashing isn’t flush with the finished brick since the brick and mortar don’t create a flat surface.


A picture helps explain things much more than a description.

Usually this gap is filled in with a polyurethane caulking. It is dependant on how wide it is. As said, a pic is needed.

Thank you! I added a picture. Let me know if another angle would be helpful. The theory is that any sort of caulking will eventually fail (and has failed) and cementing flashing into the brick is a better approach. I'm a little hesitant to chisel into the brick, though, so just curious on other's thoughts. I'm in the NE if that is relevant.
